# How can I dynamically change size of the kernel in conv2d (PyTorch)?

Tags: python, pytorch, computer-vision, conv-neural-network

How can I set a dynamical kernel size in PyTorch?

I am passing images to my network, and I would like to set my kernels to change **size** and **stride** as a function of the eccentricity of the input. Also, I would like to use circles rather than squared kernels.

Does this sound possible at all? I tried to google but had no luck. Any help would be really much appreciated!

EDIT: just to be more clear: the input images have all the same size, and I don't need to change kernel size once the net is initialized. I just need a conv layer that behaves more or less like [this](https://github.com/ArturoDeza/Piranhas/blob/master/images/Total_Foveated_Cartoon.png) (bottom images). Basically a kernel changing size as a function of eccentricity, in order to have high resolution at the center and increasingly lower resolution in the periphery (by pooling bigger and overlapping areas).

Comment: How do you define a *circle kernel* 
exactly?

Answer (score 0):

**Yes**, you can do it easily in the **forward function**..

For example, in this code I am calling to a boolean function, if the result is True I am using conv1, else I am using conv2.

```
    def forward(self, x):
        """
        In the forward function we accept a Tensor of input data and we must return
        a Tensor of output data. We can use Modules defined in the constructor as
        well as arbitrary operators on Tensors.
        """
        if boolean_func(x):
            x = self.conv1(x)
        else:
            x = self.conv2(x)
        out = self.dense1(x)
        return out
```

**In your case**, you can define two conv layers, and use the one you want by condition on the input.

In the backpropagation process, the weights of the layer you used will be updated without any intervention thanks to the computational information stored in the graph.

Comment: This assumes I know how many sizes beforehand. Ideally, I would like to avoid this and use a scale factor or max/min to define a range of size as a function of eccentricity. Additionally, the two layer would have different weights in your example.

Comment: Change the kernel size will change number of trained params of the layer, I dont think its possible to change it dynamicly in the same layer...

Comment: Sorry, probably I was not clear. The number of trained parameters (and thus the size of the kernel) will not change once the network is made. I am not planning on changing the size/stride of the kernel once the net is initialized.